# One session per user , disconnect old session when new login?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

Hi I want to allow one session per user with php! Here is what I need:  when the same user login on my site and when he is already logged , he can log in normally BUT it kills the older session ! Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Ordinarily, a session lasts for the time the user is logged in. When an already logged-in user logs in again most web apps drop the existing session and create a new one. The session id is stored on a cookie in the user's browser, and logging in again replaces that id with a new one. Can you please [edit] your question and tell us more about what you *want* to happen?

Comment: Are you talking about logging in from the same device and browser, or separate? As the above comment notes, if it's the same device and browser, then (assuming the app even allows re-login when the session is already in progress) then it should drop the existing session and re-create. If you want to detect when the user is already logged in via another browser, you'd probably have to store a field in the database against their user ID which is true whenever they have a current session, or something. But of course the statelessness of the web makes this a bit more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra table to your user in the database and call it session.
Once you login you update that row and store a hashed version of it in your $_SESSION. Because you store a new/overwrite the session when you login again you can only be logged in once. Since the other computer wouldn't have the right key in it's $_SESSION stored.

Just throwing rocks but this is an option. Not sure about safety though

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a cookie for this. Sessions get destroyed once the users closes the browser window while cookies are stored on the users computer untill they expire. To delete the older sessions when the user logs in somewhere else you could give the cookie an ID in it's value. Store the ID in a table and as soon as a user logs in with a cookie that's not in your table anymore you set the expiry date of the cookie in the past (which deletes the cookie)